# How to find unique element count in string array?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a list of towns. 20 of them in fact, but in my 20 town string array there are only 4 unique towns, but they are randomly scattered in array and can repeat. How do I find unique town count?

Comment: Create a `std::map` and `cityName` as key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::set`, e.g.

```
std::set<std::string> myset(list_of_towns.begin(), list_of_towns.end());
```

assuming your town names are in a std::vector called `list_of_towns`.

Comment: Too many assumptions for my taste.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree (including the comment upvote) but hey, with that quality of question, giving OP more than something to start googling for is really not that feasible...

Answer (score 0):

You can create `unordered_map` to store the occurrence of each town name. Then remove the entries with occurrence value > 1.

```
unordered_map<string, int> m;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(town)/sizeof(town[0])); i++){
    m[town[i]]++;
}
for(unordered_map<string, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end();){
    if(it->second > 1) it = m.erase(it);  //erase returns next iterator since C++11
    else it++;
 }
std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I am still a newbie and this is new to me, may I get an answer with full code? Just want it to print unique count. Here's the start: 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

string town[5]={"Vilnius", "Klaipeda", "Klaipeda", "Vilnius", "Kaunas"}

int main()
{

return 0;
}

Comment: @MatasLiutikas your own code belongs in your question, not in a late comment to an answer